# how to pass chrome.tabCapture stream from js to c++ PNACL native code

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

I am working on integrate a chrome extension that captures video from the current tab,  with  the PNACL SDK in order to record the video stream into a .webm file. I already did that in a only-javascript version (with whammy) but I am interested in replace whammy with native code for performance reasons.

- I wonder how to pass the stream obtained from  chrome.tabCapture.capture in js to the native side (I guess it is through a postMessage but not sure if the js stream object can be passed as is, and in which kind of c++ structure receive it at native side).

  I appreciate any suggestions or feedback,

Comment: What was the final result you got, I am doing the same thing here, I am extremely puzzled I can not figure out how to do it. I need some guidance. if you can share some parts of the code you will save me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Native Client SDK has an example plugin that does this. It's an API demo called media_stream_video.

Here are instructions on how to build and run the examples:
https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/sdk/examples

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that tutorial, I was able to get rid off the opengl part and have a basic structure for getting frames. Now I am searching about how to inject those frames into something that encode a video file, like ffmpeg. do you know if there is some chrome wrapper for that or from this point the only way is go with raw ffmpeg calls?

Comment: @bbudge my you please elaborate more on this case. I think many people are asking the same question. I have been searching for answer and looking through the code for the past week